# The image could not be displayed using Magnific Popup

Tags: magnific-popup

I have the following code and the image popup shows nothing. What am I doing wrong?
    `$('span.confluence-embedded-file-wrapper').magnificPopup({type: 'image'});`

And the HTML code:

```
<span class="confluence-embedded-file-wrapper conf-macro output-inline" data-hasbody="false" data-macro-name="sp-image">
<img class="confluence-embedded-image" src="/space2021/files/582418577/582418579/1/1563720219000/image1.png">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

It came out to doing three things.

1. Missing href. For this I added the below:

```
<script>
  count = document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;
  href ='';
  n = 0;
  while (n < (count + 1)) {
    imgsrc = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[n].getAttribute('src');
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[n].setAttribute('href', imgsrc); 
    n = n + 1;
    imgsrc ='';
  }
  </script>
```

2. Instead of before or after the magnific call, I had to add it at the end of page after the body tag. It works now.
3. Delegation :

Modified the call to

```
$('span.confluence-embedded-file-wrapper').magnificPopup({delegate: 'img' , type: 'image'});
```

Is there a way to make it work work without inserting the href attribute? src attribute is already there which is what I am pushing to href.